# Fix sidebar in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

Is there a way to fix the sidebar in shiny application. Below is the screenshot. Right now, its collapsible. But can we fix this so that it should not move

[image: r]

Below is the sample code for this

```
ui <- dashboardPage(
  
  dashboardHeader(title = "Title1"),
  
  dashboardSidebar(sidebarMenu(.......
```

Answer (score 1):

You can hide it with a piece of JavaScript using the `shinyjs` package:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(shinyjs::useShinyjs())
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  shinyjs::hide(selector = ".navbar > .sidebar-toggle")
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```